# How to update a state entry in react and display it's contents in input field before updating?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm creating a shopping cart form that can be used to add/update/delete user info. I've used react-hook-form for form submission and validation. My initial state is empty array. When user is added, objects are appended in the state array like -

```js
state = [
  { name: 'abc', age: '23' },
  { name: 'katy', age: '12' },
];
```

How can update the value in state if a div row has an edit button and it displays it in an existing input box and when i click update(another button), it updates the corresponding value.

Note- name can be same hence i can't use a state.find().

Comment: can you use id for each item of state?

Comment: As you're using react-hook-form, go through the form array related hook, functions. This will also give unique ids.

Comment: If you are listing the users you could pass an ID that could come from a map function and use it to change the state

Comment: @iunfixit, I don't have an id in state, but have an index from map function

Answer (score 0):

One approach

```
const UpdateComponent = ({ id, user, setState }) => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState({
    id: 0,
    name: "",
    age: 0
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setUserData({ id: id, name: user.name, age: user.age });
  }, [user, id]);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setUserData((currentData) => ({
      ...currentData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    setState((currentState) =>
      currentState.map((u) => (u.id === id ? userData : u))
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onChange={onChange}
        name="name"
        value={userData.name}
        placeholder="Name"
      />
      <input
        onChange={onChange}
        name="age"
        value={userData.age}
        placeholder="Age"
      />
      <button onClick={onSubmit} type="button">
        Update
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

const List = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setState(
      [
        { name: "abc", age: "23" },
        { name: "katy", age: "12" }
      ].map((u, i) => ({ ...u, id: i }))
    );
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // debug
    console.log(state);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div>
      {state.map((user) => (
          <UpdateComponent
            key={user.id}
            id={user.id}
            user={user}
            setState={setState}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Take a look https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-surf-p5cxh?file=/src/App.js

You could use the UUID package to generate the IDs:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
// Generates IDs when loading the data as example
// but ideally IDs are created on user creation
setState(
  [
    { name: "abc", age: "23" },
    { name: "katy", age: "12" }
  ].map((u) => ({ ...u, id: uuidv4() }))
);
  }, []);
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-hypatia-tjzcx

But that is not very different from the initial approach with the map index id(on the component mount), that is not ideal because we are generating IDs when the component mounts, but at least they don't keep changing on each render

> My initial state is empty array. When user is added, objects are appended in the state array like

For your case you could just have an ID that increments **each time a user is added**, or use the uuid when its added, so your data already comes with the ID